# How would you solve the letter changer in Julia?

Tags: string, julia

I found this challenge:

Using your language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

I am new in Julia, and I was challenging myself in this challenge. I found this challenge very hard in Julia lang and I could not find a solution.

Here I tried to solve in the way below, but I got error: the x value is not defined

How would you solve this?

```
function LetterChanges(stringis::AbstractString)

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

vohels = "aeiou"

for Char(x) in split(stringis, "")
    if x == 'z'
        x = 'a'
    elseif x in vohels
        uppercase(x)
        else 
        Int(x)+1
        Char(x)
        println(x)
    end
end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: There is a logic error. It says "Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet. Then capitalize every vowel in this new string". Your code checks, if it is a vowel. Then it capitalizes it or replaces it. That's different behavior.

Comment: It's unclear from your question how to handle spaces, punctuation and so on. (And BTW, it's `vowels`, not `vohels` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note:
The proposed solution works properly. However, if you would need high performance (which you probably do not given the source of your problem) it is more efficient to use string builder:

```
function LetterChanges2(str::AbstractString)
    v = Set("aeiou")
    #sprint(sizehint=sizeof(str)) do io # use on Julia 0.7 - new keyword argument
    sprint() do io # use on Julia 0.6.2
        for c in str
            c = c == 'z' ? 'a' : c+1 # we assume that we got only letters from 'a':'z'
            print(io, c in v ? uppercase(c) : c)
        end
    end
end
```

it is over 10x faster than the above.

EDIT: for Julia 0.7 this is a bit faster:

```
function LetterChanges2(str::AbstractString)
    v = BitSet(collect(Int,"aeiouy"))
    sprint(sizehint=sizeof(str)) do io # use on Julia 0.7 - new keyword argument
        for c in str
            c = c == 'z' ? 'a' : c+1 # we assume that we got only letters from 'a':'z'
            write(io, Int(c) in v ? uppercase(c) : c)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Using a preallocated `Vector{Char}` turned out roughly 20% faster than this. I guess `sizehint` will make a difference in 0.7.

Comment: BTW, for longer strings the difference becomes much more than 10x, since the allocations get totally out of hand in the other answer, and it starts slowing down progressively.

Comment: This is what I suppose is the difference - I have developed this in 0.7 and then ported it to 0.6.2 where `sprint()` has to grow an array as it is cumbersome to pass size as positional argument because it has to go before the function and you would have to define inner function explicitly instead of `do` construct. This is one of those small changes in 0.7 that make it more convenient.

Comment: I used a dictionary-based approach, which is probably cheating, but means I could just set up the upper-case vowels as values (e.g. `'d'=>'E'`). It was **much** slower than your Julia 0.6.2 solution above for small strings, but once I got up to about 100,000 characters it was slightly quicker. Any idea why that might be? I'm a beginner with Julia, so I'm just trying to get a feel for the language.

Comment: It is probably not cheating :). If you create a dict outside the function and pass it to it then it will be faster even for small strings. An even faster implementation would be to use `Vector{Char}` where you map integers from `0` to `122` to target values (lookup of `Int(c)` will be faster for vector than lookup of `c` in dictionary).

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Are there major changes in the version 0.7 of Julia? I did not get what the function sprint() does. Thank you for your help

Comment: The list of changes is massive https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md. `sprint` called with a function as a first argument opens I/O stream, passes it to that function and then converts what the function writes to this stream to `String`. In Julia 0.7 `sprint` has a new keyword argument `sizehint` which allows you to pass a hint how big the I/O buffer should be.

Answer (score 2):

There is a logic error. It says "Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet. Then capitalize every vowel in this new string". Your code checks, if it is a vowel. Then it capitalizes it or replaces it. That's different behavior. You have to first replace and then to check if it is a vowel.

You are replacing 'a' by 'Z'. You should be replacing 'z' by 'a'

The function `split(stringis, "")` returns an array of strings. You can't store these strings in `Char(x)`. You have to store them in `x` and then you can transform theses string to char with `c = x[1]`.

After transforming a char you have to store it in the variable: `c = uppercase(c)`

You don't need to transform a char into int. You can add a number to a char: `c = c + 1`

You have to store the new characters in a string and return them.

```
function LetterChanges(stringis::AbstractString)

    # some code

    str = ""
    for x in split(stringis, "")
        c = x[1]

        # logic

        str = "$str$c"
    end
    return str
end
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, could you please show me how to code what you said?

Comment: There's no need to split the string. Just write: `for c in stringis`. Also, building the string like that is very wasteful. For every iteration a totally new string is allocated that is one char longer than the previous. Better to preallocate a `Vector{Char}` of the correct length, and then convert it at the end with `String`.

Comment: @DNF: below, in parallel :), I have proposed how I think it is typically done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version that is a bit faster than @BogumilKaminski's answer on version 0.6, but that might be different on 0.7. On the other hand, it might be a little less intimidating than the `do`-block magic ;)

```
function changeletters(str::String)
    vowels = "aeiouy"
    carr = Vector{Char}(length(str))
    i = 0
    for c in str
        newchar = c == 'z' ? 'a' : c + 1
        carr[i+=1] = newchar in vowels ? uppercase(newchar) : newchar
    end
    return String(carr)
end
```

Comment: Nice. If you do look at `convert(::Type{String}, chars::AbstractVector{Char})` definition you will see that it does exactly what I have implemented (but in a bit more general way).

Comment: I have just checked on 0.7 that my implementation in 20% faster than yours (as it avoids intermediate `Vector{Char}` array you create and uses `Set` for searching which turns out to be faster). I have updated my solution with an solution that further squeezes the performance a bit with `BitSet`.

Comment: That makes sense, fewer allocations. On the other hand, on 0.6, using `Set` for searching is no faster than a string, it's identical. On 0.7 (kinda old version, though) string search is much slower than on 0.6, while `Set` is faster.

Comment: Thank you DNF, I like your solution although is not upper-casing the  vowels.
Could you please explain me this part
`carr = Vector{Char}(length(str))` ?
Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It _does_ uppercase the vowels. The `carr = ...` part pre-allocates a vector of characters, so you don't have to grow it dynamically. Then, at the end, you convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being accused of cheating, this is a dictionary-based approach:

```
function change_letters(s::String)::String
    k = collect('a':'z')
    v = vcat(collect('b':'z'), 'A')
    d = Dict{Char, Char}(zip(k, v))
    for c in Set("eiou")
        d[c - 1] = uppercase(d[c - 1])
    end
    b = IOBuffer()
    for c in s
        print(b, d[c])
    end
    return String(take!(b))
end
```

It seems to compare well in speed terms with the other Julia 0.6 methods for long strings (e.g. 100,000 characters). There's a bit of unnecessary overhead in constructing the dictionary which is noticeable on small strings, but I'm far too lazy to type out the `'a'=>'b'` construction long-hand!